# SQL select XML column from table as a xml node (instead of it being nested under another xml node)?

Tags: sql-server, xml, stored-procedures, xpath

```
DECLARE @outputXML xml 
CREATE TABLE #Temp (a varchar(128), xmlelement xml)
INSERT INTO #Temp values('1', N'<list id="1"/><list id="2"/>')
INSERT INTO #Temp values('3', N'<list id="3"/><list id="4"/>')

set @outputXML=(SELECT a as '@id', xmlelement as 'SecondMasterList' from #Temp
FOR XML PATH('MasterList'))

select @outputXML

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

The above script @outputXML throws the below XML

```
<MasterList id="1">
<SecondMasterList><list id="1" /><list id="2" /></SecondMasterList>
</MasterList>
<MasterList id="3">
<SecondMasterList><list id="3" /><list id="4" /></SecondMasterList>
</MasterList>
```

Required:
But I need @outputXML's `<list>` nested directly under `<MasterList>`. ie. without nesting it under a `<SecondMasterList>`

Expected output:

```
<MasterList id="1">
<list id="1" /><list id="2" />
</MasterList>
<MasterList id="3">
<list id="3" /><list id="4" />
</MasterList>
```

Let me know how the query should be modified for the expected output.
Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify path for an attribute

```
set @outputXML=(SELECT a as 'MasterList/@id', xmlelement as 'MasterList' from #Temp
FOR XML PATH(''))
```